# .less files returns 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, dotless

I have dotless installed on my website and it's running perfectly on my local machine and on the companys testserver but when deploying on production server it always returns 404 and I can't figure out why.

This is what I've done so far to get it to work:

Added the section

`<section name="dotless" type="dotless.Core.configuration.DotlessConfigurationSectionHandler, dotless.Core" />`

Added the mimeMap

`<staticContent>
<mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
</staticContent>`

Added the handler

`<add name="dotless" path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />`

And added the dotless element

`<dotless minifyCss="true" cache="true" />`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the handler at the correct place?

- IIS6: under system.web\httpHandlers
- IIS7: under system.webServer\handlers

Also make sure you have all less files in place. If you import other less files, all those files must be available. If a file is missing, dotless throws 404.